# Как создать файл ?

Tags: gwt, java, eclipse

Программка на Java в GWT (пытаюсь написать из под Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 1).

Не получается создать файл (открыть на запись), естественно в серверной части.

```
PrintWriter fout = null;
try {
    fout = new PrintWriter (new File(my_filename).getAbsoluteFile());
} catch (Exception e) {
    lastErrMsg = e.getMessage();
}
```

Ловит ошибку:

> `access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Documents and Settings\avp\eclipse-workspace\MyTest\war\t-users.dat write)`

Тест на той же Яве, только не из GWT проекта, прекрасно пишет в тот же файл, т.е. системные права (Windows XP) тут ни при чем.

Попытки игр с именами файла (оглавления) в java.io.FilePermission

```
perm =      new java.io.FilePermission(
//"C:\\Documents and Settings\\avp\\eclipse-workspace\\MyTest\\war\\t-users.dat"
            //abspath
            "*"
            /*dbUsersData*/,"read, write, delete");
```

ничего не изменили. В момент создания **PrintWriter** объект  **perm** cуществует (успешно печатается на консоль).

Может быть, созданный объект FilePermission надо передать в какой-нибудь метод?

В чем здесь проблема?

Или более конкретно, как записывать данные в файл на стороне сервера?

**UPD**

Мне все больше кажется, что я должен прописать в каком-то файле нечто вроде:

```
 grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${HOME}/-", "read, write, delete";
    permission org.osgi.framework.PackagePermission "*", "EXPORT";
 };
```

Но вот в какой файл Eclipse ? (Или в каком его диалоговом окошке, что сказать о привилегиях, которые д.б. Granted моему коду) ?

**UPD**

Мне уже кажется, что я должен как-то сформировать нужные мне permissions в своей Java программе и как-то прицепить их к исполняемому объекту (по моему это называется сервлет ?) т.е. к себе.

Но те ли это действия, и если те, то что конкретно делать.

**UPD**

[[@Nofate](/users/1984/nofate)](/users/1984/nofate) comment:

*Видимо это GAE-шное ограничение. Если я правильно себе представляю в развернутом приложении у вас не будет никакой файловой системы, кроме содержимого вашего WAR-а. А все данные кладутся в BigTable.
Да, и ничто не мешает вам пользовать GWT без плюшек GAE.*

======

Ответ (поскольку лимит  комментариев, используемых для обсуждения ситуации иссяк):

*Я не знаю, что такое GAE и BigTable. Хочется понять, как сервлет (если я использую правильный термин) может сохранять свои данные.*

**======**

Comment: А зачем Вам getAbsoluteFile()? Я так не делал.

Comment: getAbsoluteFile()? Откровенно говоря, особо не задумываясь взял из "Философия JAVA".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А вы пробовали через doPrivilegedAction?

Comment: Погуглил, начал пробовать. 

AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {

            public Object run() { ....

Eclipse принял. Посмотрим, что получиться.

Comment: Отлично !!!!!!!!!
@cy6erGn0m  - Ваши познания похоже стремятся к бесконечности !!!!

Файл xaxa-xaxa.xaxa Успешно создан.

Огромное спасибо. Жаль, не могу перевести Ваш комментарий в ответ.
Вопрос закрываю.

Comment: Я сделал ответом, а ваши комменты подвинул к нему ;)

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю обычно так (по-моему, удобный способ):

```
CodepagePrintStream printStream = new CodepagePrintStream(
                                      new FileOutputStream(file), "Cp1251");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            printStream.println("строка " + i);
        printStream.close();
```

Переменная `file` - класса `File`. Т.е. думаю, Вы знаете, как создать файл.
Внимание, состав класса CodepagePrintStream!!!! Я его когда-то откуда-то скачал, и радуюсь. Один добрый человек написал этот класс для записи всякого текста в потоки в нужной вам кодировке. ВОТ ОН (просто скопируйте):

```
package mdel; /**
     * CodepagePrintStream.java
     *
     * Copyright (C) 1998-2000 COMITA Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
     */
    import java.io.*;

    /**
     * Класс реализует методы PrintStream с возможностью работы в нужной кодировке.
     *
     * Обычно используется для замены стандартных System.out и System.err:
     * <pre>
     *  public static void main(String[] args)
     *  {
     *   // Установка вывода консольных сообщений в нужной кодировке
     *   try
     *     {
     *      System.setOut(new CodepagePrintStream(System.out,System.getProperty("console.encoding","Cp866")) );
     *     }
     *   catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
     *     {
     *      Msg.message(Msg.ALERT,"Unable to setup console codepage: " + e);
     *      Msg.printStackTrace(Msg.ALERT,e);
     *     }
     * </pre>
     *
     * @author Sergey Astakhov
     * @version 1.01, 24.07.2000
     */
    public class CodepagePrintStream extends PrintStream
    {
        public CodepagePrintStream(OutputStream os,String cp) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
        {
            super(os);

            this.autoFlush = false;
            this.charOut = new OutputStreamWriter(this,cp);
            this.textOut = new BufferedWriter(this.charOut);
        }

        private boolean autoFlush = false;
        private boolean trouble = false;

        /**
         * Track both the text- and character-output streams, so that their buffers
         * can be flushed without flushing the entire stream.
         */
        private BufferedWriter textOut;
        private OutputStreamWriter charOut;

        /** Check to make sure that the stream has not been closed */
        private void ensureOpen() throws IOException {
            if (out == null)
                throw new IOException("Stream closed");
        }

        /**
         * Flush the stream.  This is done by writing any buffered output bytes to
         * the underlying output stream and then flushing that stream.
         *
         * @see        java.io.OutputStream#flush()
         */
        public void flush() {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    ensureOpen();
                    out.flush();
                }
                catch (IOException x) {
                    trouble = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean closing = false; /* To avoid recursive closing */

        /**
         * Close the stream.  This is done by flushing the stream and then closing
         * the underlying output stream.
         *
         * @see        java.io.OutputStream#close()
         */
        public void close() {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (! closing) {
                    closing = true;
                    try {
                        textOut.close();
                        out.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException x) {
                        trouble = true;
                    }
                    textOut = null;
                    charOut = null;
                    out = null;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Flush the stream and check its error state.  The internal error state
         * is set to <code>true</code> when the underlying output stream throws an
         * <code>IOException</code> other than <code>InterruptedIOException</code>,
         * and when the <code>setError</code> method is invoked.  If an operation
         * on the underlying output stream throws an
         * <code>InterruptedIOException</code>, then the <code>PrintStream</code>
         * converts the exception back into an interrupt by doing:
         * <pre>
         *     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         * </pre>
         * or the equivalent.
         *
         * @return True if and only if this stream has encountered an
         *         <code>IOException</code> other than
         *         <code>InterruptedIOException</code>, or the
         *         <code>setError</code> method has been invoked
         */
        public boolean checkError() {
            if (out != null)
                flush();
            return trouble;
        }

        /**
         * Set the error state of the stream to <code>true</code>.
         *
         * @since JDK1.1
         */
        protected void setError() {
            trouble = true;
        }

        /*
                 * Exception-catching, synchronized output operations,
                 * which also implement the write() methods of OutputStream
                 */

        /**
         * Write the specified byte to this stream.  If the byte is a newline and
         * automatic flushing is enabled then the <code>flush</code> method will be
         * invoked.
         *
         * <p> Note that the byte is written as given; to write a character that
         * will be translated according to the platform's default character
         * encoding, use the <code>print(char)</code> or <code>println(char)</code>
         * methods.
         *
         * @param  b  The byte to be written
         * @see #print(char)
         * @see #println(char)
         */
        public void write(int b) {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    ensureOpen();
                    out.write(b);
                    if ((b == '\n') && autoFlush)
                        out.flush();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            catch (IOException x) {
                trouble = true;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write <code>len</code> bytes from the specified byte array starting at
         * offset <code>off</code> to this stream.  If automatic flushing is
         * enabled then the <code>flush</code> method will be invoked.
         *
         * <p> Note that the bytes will be written as given; to write characters
         * that will be translated according to the platform's default character
         * encoding, use the <code>print(char)</code> or <code>println(char)</code>
         * methods.
         *
         * @param  buf   A byte array
         * @param  off   Offset from which to start taking bytes
         * @param  len   Number of bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte buf[], int off, int len) {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    ensureOpen();
                    out.write(buf, off, len);
                    if (autoFlush)
                        out.flush();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            catch (IOException x) {
                trouble = true;
            }
        }

        /*
                 * The following private methods on the text- and character-output streams
                 * always flush the stream buffers, so that writes to the underlying byte
                 * stream occur as promptly as with the original PrintStream.
                 */

        private void write(char buf[]) {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    ensureOpen();
                    textOut.write(buf);
                    textOut.flush();
                    charOut.flush();
                    if (autoFlush) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
                            if (buf[i] == '\n')
                                out.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            catch (IOException x) {
                trouble = true;
            }
        }

        private void write(String s) {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    ensureOpen();
                    textOut.write(s);
                    textOut.flush();
                    charOut.flush();
                    if (autoFlush && (s.indexOf('\n') >= 0))
                        out.flush();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            catch (IOException x) {
                trouble = true;
            }
        }

        private void newLine() {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    ensureOpen();
                    textOut.newLine();
                    textOut.flush();
                    charOut.flush();
                    if (autoFlush)
                        out.flush();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            catch (IOException x) {
                trouble = true;
            }
        }

        /* Methods that do not terminate lines */

        /**
         * Print a boolean value.  The string produced by <code>{@link
         * String#valueOf(boolean)} is translated into bytes according to
         * the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written
         * in exactly the manner of the <code>{@link #write(int)} method.
         *
         * @param      b   The <code>boolean</code> to be printed
         */
        public void print(boolean b) {
            write(b ? "true" : "false");
        }

        /**
         * Print a character.  The character is translated into one or more bytes
         * according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes
         * are written in exactly the manner of the <code>{@link #write(int)}
         * method.
         *
         * @param      c   The <code>char</code> to be printed
         */
        public void print(char c) {
            write(String.valueOf(c));
        }

        /**
         * Print an integer.  The string produced by <code>{@link
         * String#valueOf(int)} is translated into bytes according to the
         * platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in
         * exactly the manner of the <code>{@link #write(int)} method.
         *
         * @param      i   The <code>int</code> to be printed
         */
        public void print(int i) {
            write(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        /**
         * Print a long integer.  The string produced by <code>{@link
         * String#valueOf(long)} is translated into bytes according to
         * the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written
         * in exactly the manner of the <code>{@link #write(int)} method.
         *
         * @param      l   The <code>long</code> to be printed
         */
        public void print(long l) {
            write(String.valueOf(l));
        }

        /**
         * Print a floating-point number.  The string produced by <code>{@link
         * String#valueOf(float)} is translated into bytes according to
         * the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written
         * in exactly the manner of the <code>{@link #write(int)} method.
         *
         * @param      f   The <code>float</code> to be printed
         */
        public void print(float f) {
            write(String.valueOf(f));
        }

        /**
         * Print a double-precision floating-point number.  The string produced by
         * <code>{@link String#valueOf(double)} is translated into bytes
         * according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes
         * are written in exactly the manner of the <code>{@link #write(int)}
         * method.
         *
         * @param      d   The <code>double</code> to be printed
         */
        public void print(double d) {
            write(String.valueOf(d));
        }

        /**
         * Print an array of characters.  The characters are converted into bytes
         * according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes
         * are written in exactly the manner of the <code>{@link #write(int)}
         * method.
         *
         * @param      s   The array of chars to be printed
         *
         * @throws  NullPointerException  If <code>s</code> is <code>null</code>
         */
        public void print(char s[]) {
            write(s);
        }

        /**
         * Print a string.  If the argument is <code>null</code> then the string
         * <code>"null"</code> is printed.  Otherwise, the string's characters are
         * converted into bytes according to the platform's default character
         * encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the
         * <code>{@link #write(int)} method.
         *
         * @param      s   The <code>String</code> to be printed
         */
        public void print(String s) {
            if (s == null) {
                s = "null";
            }
            write(s);
        }

        /**
         * Print an object.  The string produced by the <code>{@link
         * String#valueOf(Object)} method is translated into bytes
         * according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes
         * are written in exactly the manner of the <code>{@link #write(int)}
         * method.
         *
         * @param      obj   The <code>Object</code> to be printed
         */
        public void print(Object obj) {
            write(String.valueOf(obj));
        }

        /* Methods that do terminate lines */

        /**
         * Terminate the current line by writing the line separator string.  The
         * line separator string is defined by the system property
         * <code>line.separator</code>, and is not necessarily a single newline
         * character (<code>'\n'</code>).
         */
        public void println() {
            newLine();
        }

        /**
         * Print a boolean and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
         * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(boolean)} and then <code>{@link
         * #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(boolean x) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Print a character and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
         * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(char)} and then <code>{@link
         * #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(char x) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Print an integer and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
         * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(int)} and then <code>{@link
         * #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(int x) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Print a long and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
         * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(long)} and then <code>{@link
         * #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(long x) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Print a float and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
         * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(float)} and then <code>{@link
         * #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(float x) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Print a double and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
         * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(double)} and then <code>{@link
         * #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(double x) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Print an array of characters and then terminate the line.  This method
         * behaves as though it invokes <code>{@link #print(char[])} and then
         * <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(char x[]) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Print a String and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
         * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(String)} and then <code>{@link
         * #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(String x) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Print an Object and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
         * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(Object)} and then <code>{@link
         * #println()}</code>.
         */
        public void println(Object x) {
            synchronized (this) {
                print(x);
                newLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, это все здорово.

Но у меня проблема, как я понимаю, с правами, которые Security Manager предоставляет (Granted) моему коду.  Где в Eclipse эта фигня прописывается ? Вот в чем вопрос. 

Код НЕ Web Application работает как задумано, а в WEB нет прав на запись. В чем СУЩЕСТВЕННОЕ для моих попыток различие конфигураций для JVM (?) - не могу найти.

Comment: А зачем это всё надо? :O Это же огромный класс, вводящий в заблуждение, к тому же.

Answer (score 0):

Прописывайте разрешения в манифесте приложения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Теперь вы можете сохранять информацию и читать с флешки.
Данный код создаёт файл и сохраняет в нём входные данные:

```
boolean createProjectFile(Context context, File targetFile, String txt){
        try{
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(targetFile);
            out.print(txt);
            out.close();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Если не работает, то проверьте правильность расположения и наименования файла который вы хотите сохранить. Смотрите логи выполнения (Logcat).